# stored procedure mysql returning each result column from each row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want for the stored procedure to return the value of each column of my select.

I have customer table with column 1 column 2 and column 3.
I have a select which returns 10 rows and I want to get for each row the result of column 1, column2 and column3.

How can I do this?

```
  BEGIN
  DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE col1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE col2 VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE col3 INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) into n FROM customer;
  set i=1;
  WHILE i<=n DO
  SELECT column1 FROM customer WHERE id=i INTO col1;
  SELECT column2 FROM customer WHERE id=i INTO col2;
  SELECT column3 FROM customer WHERE id=i INTO col3;
  SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
  END
```

How can I get each value col1, col2 and col3 to display it and to use it for the next treatment.

How can I call this stored procedure in MySQL?

Comment: Can you expand on your second last sentence please - a simple select will display the columns so I don't get what the problem is or what you mean by next treatment. 'How can i call' in mysql call procedure name(parameters)

Comment: @P Salmon In this sentence "How can i get each value col1,col2 and col3 to display it and to use it for the next treatment.", I said that i want to display value of col1,col2 and col3 . Iwant to see this content. And my question is how can i complete my stored procedure and call it with parameter? can you show me if you have an idea

Comment: The last sentence in my first comment tells you how to call a stored procedure , repeated here - call procedure name(parameters) - Have you tried this? Did you have a problem? See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

Saving your logic you may use

```
BEGIN
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM customer 
WHERE id <= ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM customer );
END
```

Comment: hello @Akina , I saving  my logic with your suggestion, my question is how to call this stored procedure with parameter to and display the result of col1 col 2 and col3 for each row.

Comment: @obela06 *call this stored procedure with parameter* I do NOT see any parameter (or something which may be an external parameter).